# Single unexpected null value in a request while testing a rest controller with soapUI

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, post, soapui

I have a Controller which receives a request object via SoapUI (screen below). What confuses me it is that only one of the 2 attributes of this request object is null (it should not be), the other it is what it is meant to be.

This is my Controller:

```
@RestController
public class RestituzioneController {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestituzioneController.class);
    @Autowired
    RestService restService;
    
    @PostMapping(value="/restituzione")
    public RestituzioneResponse restituzione(@RequestBody RestituzioneRequest request) {
        logger.info("Start --------------- ");
        logger.info("request {}",request.toString());
```

and Request class being (I'm using Lombok):

```
@Data
public class RestituzioneRequest {
    private @NotEmpty String code;
    private @NotEmpty String numP;
}
```

After executing a POST call through SoapUI (screen below) this is what the log states:

> Start ---------------
> request RestituzioneRequest(code=null,
> numP=12XXX0000123)

SoapUI parameters:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with other tools eg. [Postman](https://www.postman.com/)
I'm pretty sure your code is perfectly fine, It might be conflict by SoapUI version issue.

Comment: thanks for your response, today worked like a charm and i could not figure out why... programming being programming i guess :P